# Data manupilation in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames **result** and **annotation** as follow;

result 
**ID   Score1   Score2   Score3**

 1       s11         s12       s13
3       s21         s22       s23
6       s31         s32       s33

annotation
**ID   Ann1   Ann2**   

 1           a11          a12           
 2          a21         a22           
 3          a31          a32           
 4          a41          a42           
 5          a51          a52           
 6          a61          a62           
 7          a71          a72           


I want output as follow:
output 
**ID      Score1      Score2      Score3      Ann1       Ann2**

 1           s11             s12                 s13             a11           a12
 3           s21             s22                 s23             a31           a32
 6           s31             s32                 s33             a61           a62

ID is common between two tables

Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Do you need `merge(result, annotation)` ? Why `ID` 3 and 6 are selected in the output, shouldn't it be 2 and 3 instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `left_join()` from dplyr:

```
> library(dplyr)
> left_join(result, annotation, by = "ID")
  ID Score1 Score2 Score3 Ann1 Ann2
1  1    s11    s12    s13  a11  a12
2  3    s21    s22    s23  a31  a32
3  6    s31    s32    s33  a61  a62
```